# Testing Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototyping

Is there anywhere online where you can test Ruby on Rails?

Mainly testing getting data from models. Looking for something similar to http://jsfiddle.net/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, and I'd like to think I do, you want a website which you could hit with your app that would let you correctly build queries using your ActiveRecord models?

No, there isn't such a place, namely because your models are different from my models and there isn't any common code. If you need to test getting data from your models, you can use the testing libraries of which there are many (Test::Unit, RSpec, MiniTest/Spec, etc, etc).

Comment: No I was looking for something with mock models, that I could query against and iterate over. I am learning rails and want to try some things out but don't have a server setup.

Comment: Rails comes with a built-in server, no need to set one up. It also uses the sqlite database, which you should already have installed, if you're on the mac or linux. Add data through your models in the test setups and run them. Don't worry about mocking right now.